# getting CORS error while using AWS api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

I have created a API from this AWS tutorial  [https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3/#:~:text=Upload%20an%20image%20file%20to%20S3%20by%20invoking%20your%20API,API%20in%20Amazon%20API%20Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3/#:%7E:text=Upload%20an%20image%20file%20to%20S3%20by%20invoking%20your%20API,API%20in%20Amazon%20API%20Gateway).

This API Uploads Images to s3 directly from API Gateway I have enabled CORS from API gateway and while using postman i am getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * but while using it with react on local host I am getting CORS error

Comment: There's no `E` in CORS.